# BCrypt.Verify not working for c# asp.net web application

Tags: c#, hash, bcrypt

I am trying to verify a hashed password that is hashed in the register page, when I try to verify the hashed password with a entered password from the login, false is always returned.

I am hashing the password so:

```
string hashPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(Password);
```

The hashpassword is then saved to the database.

I try to verify the password so:

```
bool validPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(ProvidedPassword, StoredPassword);

            Debug.WriteLine(validPassword);

            if (validPassword)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ProvidedPassword + " is valid");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Passwords do not match");
            }
```

I am using [this source](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net) from github.

I have tried multiple methods and still always returns a false value.

Comment: The hash password is a string so you should be able to compare the two stings and both should be identical.  If they are not identical than you either didn't start with the same string before you hashed or you are using a different hash algorithm.

Comment: How you are saving string in database? have you checked your table encoding ?

Comment: @jdweng I am using Bcrypt.net-Next to hash the passwords, the passwords are the same when registered and when logged in.

Comment: @MohammadOlfatmiri I am saving the string to the database using a stored procedure, how do I check my tables encoding?

Comment: Only by repeating using known encoding.   Passwords are not reversible.

Comment: @jdweng is there a better way of hashing and verifying a password?

Comment: No.  What you are doing is good. You just have to make sure you do same thing when storing and comparing.  It is possible that you are not comparing because you are using different version of Net when storing than what you are using now.

Comment: @jdweng How can I check that, it's in the same project so I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: The string in both sections of the code should produce same hash string.  If they do not then something is different in the way you are using the hash or the are using a different library.  Maybe you need to recompile the entire project to make sure both sections of the code are using same version of Net.

Comment: @jdweng If I hash the password on the same page as the verifying it works, once I hash the password on one page and verify on a different page it returns false

Comment: The two pages need to be compiled with same version of Net.

Comment: @jdweng they're both running on .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: Do both pages use the same hash algorithm?  Either the algorithm being called (or parameters) are different or the version of Net is different.  The same input to the same hash algorithm should always get same results.

Comment: @jdweng I use the code as above, I don't set any parameters for the Hashing

Comment: Make sure that your `StoredPassword` (which is actually StoredPasswordHash) is stored in a db field of `varchar(255)`. An often problem is that the field is too small (BCrypt requires 60 characters) and will be truncated.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I have the data type as NVARCHAR(max) could that be an issue?

Comment: @JarredSoekoe - So it is an SQL-Server database? Then according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it would mean that the string can be huge, unless a maximum is explicitely defined (a value instead of max). Just ensure that the value you get with `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword()` is identical to the value you use in `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify()`.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I found the error, I am using a stored procedure to write to a user table but my parameters for the stored procedure didn't match the tables parameters, thanks for the help

Comment: in my case the password length in the database was set to `nvarchar(50)` that it gets truncated when the hash string length is greater than `50`. I set it to `nvarchar(max)` and it worked

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue, my stored procedure parameters did not match my tables paremeters